# How to view all relationships in Puppet for a given host?

Tags: relationship, puppet

I am trying to work with a Puppet repo that over the years has turned into something worse than a snake mating ball. In addition, the repo once controlled two infrastructures that ran together for two completely different services, but while the infrastructures were split, the repos were not.

I am now faced with trying to make changes that will affect one, but not both infrastructures, and part of the problem is understanding what controls what.

Is there a tool of any kind that will take a hostname or host class as input and graphically show me all other entities (modules, templates, files, whatever) that have any impact on that hostname or class?

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is. It's Rspec.

**General approach:**

I realise this is probably not the answer you are hoping for*, but you need to begin by writing Rspec-puppet unit tests that provide complete test coverage for your code base.

I have done this more than once and that's why I have written a tool that can help in a situation like this: [create_specs](https://github.com/alexharv074/create_specs). I also wrote a [blog](https://alexharv074.github.io/2017/05/31/using-create_specs-to-refactor-puppet.html) post on how to use it to assist you.

Turning to your specific question:

> Is there a tool of any kind that will take a hostname or host class as input and graphically show me all other entities (modules, templates, files, whatever) that have any impact on that hostname or class?

There is of course Puppet's built-in graphing logic and if you have Puppet Enterprise there is [node graph](https://puppet.com/docs/pe/2017.3/explore_with_node_graph.html).

But honestly, the unit test route is truly the only reliable way to approach this task.

The method is as follows:

- Write a *node*-level Rspec-puppet test for all known nodes.
- Using my tool or otherwise ensure that you generate an Rspec test case that simply compiles the catalog. Use the trick I [documented](https://alexharv074.github.io/2016/03/16/dumping-the-catalog-in-rspec-puppet.html) to write out the catalog as a JSON file.
- Consider the data too. If your classes respond to conditions based on differences in input data, you recompile for each pathway through the code using different data.

**Now for detecting "modules, templates, files, whatever":**

*For nodes, classes, modules, and manifest files:*

You can then use a JQ query like this to find every class used in that catalog and the lines and files in your manifests:

```
▶ jq -jr '.resources[] | select(.line!=null) | .type, " ", .title, " (", .file, ":", .line, ")\n"' myclass.json 
Accounts::User joed (/Users/alexharvey/git/home/puppet-test/spec/fixtures/modules/test/manifests/init.pp:3)
Group joed (/Users/alexharvey/git/home/puppet-test/spec/fixtures/modules/accounts/manifests/user.pp:207)
User joed (/Users/alexharvey/git/home/puppet-test/spec/fixtures/modules/accounts/manifests/user.pp:249)
...
```

*For static files referenced by File source parameters:*

These can be found using a JQ query like:

```
▶ jq '.resources[] | select((.type=="File") and (.parameters.source!=null)) | .parameters.source' myclass.json 
"puppet:///mymodule/file"
```

*For templates:*

As for templates, they are unfortunately not mentioned explicitly in the catalog. But once you have tests for all nodes, it is easy to detect the files that are unused: just delete the suspect file, run all tests, and see if anything fails.

*For Hiera keys:*

Unfortunately I don't have a good solution for Hiera keys at this time. Leave them till last and test the ones you think are unused by deleting and then running the tests again.

---

In general, there is a great blog series [here](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/refactoring-legacy-code-part-1-the-golden-master--cms-20331) on refactoring legacy code that is worth looking at, but it is not Puppet related.

The good news is if you do all the above, you'll come out the other side of the process as a much improved and more confident developer. But in my experience, if you try to find a short cut that doesn't involve providing the missing tests, I think a world of pain lies ahead! Good luck.

---

* I make that assumption because I think you would not be asking the question otherwise!

Comment: I would argue octocatalog-diff does this more naturally than rspec-puppet, but otherwise good write up on using unit testing for this.

Comment: I think it would be painful to use octocatalog-diff after becoming fluent in the approach I recommend, and I do encourage people to read my blog post, which is written as an easy to follow tutorial with sample code on Github. Octo is good but it doesn't give you test driven development when you come out the other the end of the tunnel. How would you use it to identify unused conditional paths in the code? Test the logic in an ERB template? Run embedded YAML file content into yamllint? etc etc. I always discourage people from trying to find shortcuts to avoid learning unit testing.

Comment: Definitely not what I need. I need simple visualization, nothing more. Not trying to save or refactor the repo.

Comment: Ok I misunderstood. It sounded like you’re the new maintainer trying to fix this all up. I am not aware of any tool that gives you such visualization. Perhaps octocatalog-diff is in fact best for your requirement.

Comment: By the way, even for a one-off change Rspec is still how I would quickly do whatever you’re trying to do but I acknowledge that it may not be worth it for you to invest time learning it if you’re not the maintainer.

Comment: Also, if you make the question (or ask a new question) more specific with details of your problem I can also show you how to make this change safely.